# Using templates to iterate across struct fields at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, directx-11

I work as a TA in a class that teaches DirectX 11 and the current problem is the D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC array that generates the input layout. The instructor considers it ugly and "close to hardware." In the instructor's opinion there should be a clean and pretty function we can simply provide our vertex structure to and get an appropriate input layout back. I am attempting to write this function.

I've done some research and the general consensus is that, because C++ does not have reflection, it's not directly possible, but there is an ugly (by a certain measure) workaround using macros and boost phoenix. Unfortunately, I don't have access to Boost. My technology limitation is C++, Visual Studios Community 2017, the Windows 10 SDK, and the June 2010 DirectX 11 SDK. I realize DirectX is already included with the Windows SDK, but there are some utilities we want from the June 2010 version.

It is apparent that I can't write a runtime function to perform this task, but what about a compile time function with templates. All sources I've found thus far have talked about runtime and I have yet to discover a source talking about iterating across struct fields at compile time. I have some experience with templates, but not enough to know whether this is possible or not, let alone how to start. I was hoping someone here might have an idea.

This is my ideal solution:

```
struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT3 col;
    XMFLOAT3 norm;
    .
    .
    .
};

const char*[] bindings = {
    "POSITION",
    "COLOR",
    "NORMAL",
    .
    .
    .
};

//Takes a struct as template and a list of semantic bindings to create
//an array of D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESCs for runtime processing.
template <typename T>
constexpr D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC* processStruct(const char** semantics)
{
    //what do I put here?
}

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC* layoutDescriptor = processStruct<Vertex>(bindings);
```

Comment: If you want iterable members why not use a `std::vector`/`std::array` if they are the same type or a `std::tuple` if they need to be different?

Comment: The best you're going to get for iterating over members without reflection in the language is something like the magic_get library.

Comment: An iterable of member pointers would get you close... if they all have the same type (`XMFLOAT3`)...

Comment: I suggest to take an opposite approach. Instead of iterating over elements you can define vertex structure as composition of predefined blocks with each block including description. e.g. `pos_t` block with data type `XMFLOAT3`, format `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` semantic name `"POSITION"`. Such blocks can be easily reused to form various input descriptions.

Comment: not really sure what you're asking. What should be the output of processStruct in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear for me how you will build the D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC using the Vertex-Structor and binding strings. Nevertheless the following try may help you achieving your goal:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

const char* bin[] = {
    "pos",
    "col",
    "normal",
    "other"
};

class desc {
    public:
    constexpr desc() : desText(0){}
    constexpr desc(const char * str): desText(str) {}
    constexpr desc operator+(const desc) { return *this; }
    void printName() { std::cout << desText << std::endl;}
    const char* desText;
};

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;

template <int N, int I=N-1>
class Table : public Table<N, I-1>
{
public:
    static const desc dummy;
};

template <int N>
class Table<N, 0>
{
public:
    static const desc dummy;
    static desc array[N];
};

template <int N, int I>
const desc Table<N, I>::dummy = Table<N, 0>::array[I] = desc(bin[I]) + Table<N, I-1>::dummy;

template <int N>
const desc Table<N, 0>::dummy = Table<N, 0>::array[0] = desc(bin[0]);

template <int N>
desc Table<N, 0>::array[N];

template class Table<ARRAY_SIZE>;

int main(int, char**)
{
    for (int i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        Table<ARRAY_SIZE>::array[i].printName();
}
```

It converts the a binding list to an array of desc classes.

[live example](http://cpp.sh/2dyce)

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm after, but it's enough to get me started. Thank you.